# CSS div element containers parameters doesn't show up accordingly

Tags: html, css

I am learning the basic to create a div containers with the parameters designated in CSS. The problem is that doesn't show up accordingly when i open it even with different web engines. I am practicing aligning it with the clear and float tags.

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #990000;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

#content {
  bacground-color: green;
  height: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  border: 5px dashed rgb(0, 38, 153);
}

#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h2>Music Genres</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Rock</li>
    <li>Jazz</li>
    <li>Instrumental</li>
    <li>Pop</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: not the issue - but you have a typo in the #content css -  bacground-color: green; should be  background-color: green;

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap your `<div>`s with the standard HTML boilerplate that looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you have to connect the CSS to the HTML.

You can learn more about the different ways to connect CSS to HTML here.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Using the "Internal Style Sheet" method mentioned in the article above it would look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <style>

      #menu {
        background-color: #990000;
        height: 50%;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        border: 10px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: left;
      }

      #content {
        bacground-color: green;
        height: 50%;
        width: 75%;
        float: right;
        border: 5px dashed rgb(0, 38, 153);
      }

      #footer {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="menu">
        <h2>Music Genres</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Rock</li>
        <li>Jazz</li>
        <li>Instrumental</li>
        <li>Pop</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind though that you won't see the blue background for #footer or the background for #content because unless you put `height:` or `width:` CSS rules on the `<div></div>` elements. They only take up the space of their content. Since they don't have any content currently their styles won't be rendered to the screen.

so you need to put some text inside the divs for the browser to render them and you will be able to see the background colors.

and take a second look at the "background-color:" rule inside #content.

Hope this helped, happy hacking!

Comment: I miss to point it out that is an external style sheet with the link tag in the header area.